# mssql extension in mamp

Tags: sql-server, mamp

Im having a trouble to enable mssql in mamp, I have followed a tutorial to install php and freetds, i have the mssql.so extension, then copy paste it in mamp php extensions folder, then edit the php.ini in mamp to add extension=mssql.so, but when I restart mamp and enter the phpinfo() I got this:

[image][image]

[image]

For some reason the mssql doesn't enable, can anyone help me?

Comment: same here with me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206977/mamp-php-5-6-2-mssql-so-extension-not-installing