# MAMP PHP 5.6.2 mssql.so extension not installing

Tags: php, sql-server, mamp

I'm having trouble installing the `mssql.so` extension in `MAMP` on Yosemite.  I've followed the following tutorial multiple times, with no luck:

http://blog.benjaminwalters.net/?p=10

I'm using PHP `v5.6.2`; therefore, used/compiled the `5.6.2` version from source when following that section of the tutorial.  I've placed the `mssql.so` library file in the extensions directory as instructed and added the appropriate `extension=mssql.so` line to the correct version of the `php.ini` file as displayed from the phpInfo page, in the `Loaded Configuration File` section of the `MAMP` start portal.

After these things, the same phpInfo page still does not display the `mssql` sub-section in the installed extensions area and I am still getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /Users/sadmicrowave/Documents/Coding/Astoria/bin/commonfunctionlibrary.php on line 16
```

I'm not sure what else to do to try and install this extension and get `mssql_connect()` to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: same issue :/... did you ever have any luck?

Comment: Actually no, I gave up and just used an Ubuntu image in a docker container with port 80 exposed for web access.